# JSHint file location to add "-W041": false

Tags: javascript, jshint

i want to find the location of jshint file for adding below code but i cannot find where the jshint file.

```
{
    "-W041": false
}
```

I installed JSLint via notepad++ plugin manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create file `.jshintrc` in root folder of your project and place your settings into it.